# Github SSH key ignored

Tags: git, github

I have a few (well three) Github repositories. I can push to two of them using my SSH key without requiring username / password. However, with the third, I get asked for my username/pwd every time.

Having looked here and elsewhere, the general advice seems to be that I am accessing github via http instead of SSH, so I followed the advice to set it to SSH.

These are the steps that I undertook:

1)

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Hi adent! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

(Note: No errors)

2)

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:adent/MyRepo.git
$
```

(Note: No errors)

But.... Trying a "push" still required my username/password, so I dug a little deeper and found this:

3)

```
$ git remote -v
MyRepo  https://github.com/adent/MyRepo (fetch)
MyRepo  https://github.com/adent/MyRepo (push)
origin  git@github.com:adent/MyRepo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:adent/MyRepo.git (push)
```

This did not look right, so I checked the following:

4)
`cd ~/my_other_project`

5)

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:adent/MyOtherProject.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:adent/MyOtherProject.git (push)
```

So... Am I right in thinking that github is still holding on to the HTTP form of access for MyRepo? If so, how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You have two remotes in your first repo.  You're probably pushing to `MyRepo`.

Comment: @StephenNewell - Well I thought as much. But the question is - How do I clean it up so that I have only one remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove your deprecated remote url using HTTPS, add your SSH remote url and then change the upstream of your branch to the other one using SSH.

Doing as follows:

1. `git remote remove MyRepo` To remove your deprecated HTTPS remote url.
2. `git remote add origin git@github.com:adent/MyRepo.git` To add your SSH remote url (Looks like you've already done this one)
3. `git push -u origin <branch_name>` To track your branch with the remote one.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! It all works now. I appreciate your help. Thanks again.